# Case insensitive search and mark matching cells

Tags: excel, vba

I already asked earlier about a certain code and the answer worked flawlessly! Trying to apply what I learned from it on this different code, but it's giving me an error. Edited this code from something that has loop and Do Until, but it was not treating the first row.

My goal is to find cells with values starting with the declared targetvalues then change row colors. I also want to make this search case insensitive.

```
Sub colortargets()
Dim iRow As Long

Dim targetvalues(1 To 3) As String

targetvalues(1) = "ABC"
targetvalues(2) = "AAC"
targetvalues(3) = "AAB4"


'check if match

For i = 1 To 3
For j = 3 To 4
For iRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
val = UCase(Left(Cells(iRow, 1).Value, j))
If val = targetvalues(i) Then
Rows(iRow).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 34

Next j
Next i


End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: the `If` statement is missing `End If`. It helps to include more specific details like the error message and on what line so that we don't have to guess :]

Comment: @slai, thanks. I added 'End If' after 'Next i' and got the error message "Compile error: Function call on left-hand side of assignment must return Variant or Object".

Comment: if you don't get any code line highlighted, you can select Break In Class Module in the General Options http://www.cpearson.com/excel/BreakInClassModule.aspx

Comment: it should be in this order `.ColorIndex = 34 : End If : Next iRow : Next j : Next i`

Comment: @slai followed the order you said, but it's still giving me the same error message then highlighting `val =` before `UCase...`

Comment: ah `Val` is a VBA function name, so use different variable name

Comment: There you go! Thanks, @slai! Worked perfectly! :D

Comment: @slai, it worked, but not after adding more `targetvalues(1 to 31)` to the string. changed all necessary values, but still a no go.

Comment: FWIW - Your `j` loop could be removed if you used `UCase(Left(Cells(iRow, 1).Value, Len(targetvalues(i))))`.  That would also stop a cell value of `"AABD"` being matched against the target value of `"AAB4"`.

Answer (score -1):

I am not a fan of loops, so here is an `AutoFilter` alternative (but can't test  if it can be case sensitive):

```
Option Compare Binary       ' this is the default string comparison

Sub colorTargets()

    Cells.CurrentRegion.AutoFilter 1, Array("ABC*", "AAC*", "AAB4*"), xlFilterValues

    Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 34

    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False    ' turn off the AutoFilter

End Sub
```

Comment: noted. will try this out and get back to you. Thanks so much! :D